# How to trigger updateElements when hide modal?

Tags: elementtype, javascript, updating

Is it possible to refresh an element's list when closing a modal? I have a modal ready with:

```
onHide : function(){
    //but all what I tried doesn't work here

    //1: This will do the trick, but there is some bug with "Double-instantiating a select on an element" then the check box for the actions appear multiple times.
    Craft.elementIndex = Craft.createElementIndex('Plugin_ElementType', $('#main'), {
        context:        'index',
        storageKey:     'elementindex.Plugin_ElemenetType'
    });

    //2 I was searching for some global function as updateElements
    something like this: Craft.cp.updateElements()
    or: Craft.Plugin_ElementType.updateElements(); but no success

}
```

I need this because in that modal I change, delete data from my elements so I have to update the list, if is possible without to reload the page of course. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try already? A reference to updateElements should work, as long as you're using the right instance of it.

Comment: I updated my question with What I tested.

Answer (score 3):

If the page is rendered from a template that extends `_layouts/elementindex`, then the Element Index class instance is available at `Craft.elementIndex`. So all you’d need to do is include this in the settings object when creating your Modal instance:

```javascript
onHide: function() {
    Craft.elementIndex.updateElements();
}
```